# Does Saiku Analytics Plugin support 'Style' Attributes on Format String?

Tags: colors, string-formatting, mondrian, saiku

I am trying to apply some color formatting on my results using Saiku Analytics, without success. I tried everything, following the following recommendations to apply formatting in the Schema .xml

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?173272-Changing-Color-of-measures
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?73935-Calculated-Member-Format-String

as well as directly trying to apply custom format on the calculated members menu in Saiku Analytics.

[Mondrian Documentation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/mdx.php#Format_strings) reads:

"The format string can even contain 'style' attributes which are interpreted specially by JPivot. If present, JPivot will render cells in color."

Apart from that, I haven't been able to find any evidence that Saiku supports 'style' as well. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Following the advice of this post
https://groups.google.com/a/saiku.meteorite.bi/forum/#!topic/user/Gb4AGqU87GY
I managed to apply formatting on my fields by changing my schema.

My calculated measure is the following:

```
    <CalculatedMember name="Exclude Appraiser Role 2 Average Score" dimension="Measures" formula="IIF(([Measures].[Appraiser Role 2 Count],[Appraisee].[Appraisee]) &#60; 3,NULL,IIF([Measures].[Score_1] + [Measures].[Score_2] + [Measures].[Score_3] + [Measures].[Score_4] + [Measures].[Score_5] = 0,NULL,[Measures].[Total Question Score] / ([Measures].[Score_1] + [Measures].[Score_2] + [Measures].[Score_3] + [Measures].[Score_4] + [Measures].[Score_5])))">
        <CalculatedMemberProperty name="FORMAT_STRING" expression="IIF([Measures].[Appraiser Role 2 Average Score] &#60; 3, &#34;|#,###.##|style=red&#34; , &#34;|#,###.##|style=green&#34;)"/>     
    </CalculatedMember>
```

My question now is the following? Where can I find a complete documentation (or more examples at least) about the formatting options that are available?

For example, I am aware about 'arrow' and 'style' attributes but which is the complete list of values they take? Which paradigm do they follow? Mondrian documentation states that format string follows from Visual Basic formatting but this hint didn't prove helpful at all.

EDIT 2: As expected, colors are HTML. Question remains about arrows and other possible available attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this : http://jira.meteorite.bi/browse/SKU-1112

The difficulty is that this formatting must be done by Saiku (not Mondrian), so it must implement an interpreter of the formatting clauses and this not a simple task.